# Passing Parameters to a stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am working on a project that accepts 3 different parameters, the date is required and the First and Last name are optional. We setup the query below, but even if I change the parameters on the report (SSRS) it still looks at @LetterCreated as being '1/1/1950', any ideas on how I can get this to just accept the parameters? We set the date this way because we want the report to show with all of the reports when it is initially opened.

```
Alter Proc
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @LetterCreated DATETIME,
    @FirstName VARCHAR(20),
    @LastName VARCHAR(20) 

    SELECT @LetterCreated = '1/1/1950'
    SELECT @FirstName = ''
    SELECT @LastName = ''

    SELECT  
        LETTERCREATETIME,
        Firstname,
        LastName,
    From RedFlagAddress

    WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @LetterCreated='1/1/1950' 
             THEN '1/1/1950' 
             ELSE ISNULL(LETTERCREATETIME, '07/05/81')
        END = @LetterCreated 
    AND (LastName LIKE @LASTNAME + '%' AND FirstName LIKE @FirstNAME + '%')
    END
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related but you should definitely stop referring to dates in that manner. the ISO date formats are 'YYYYMMDD' and 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.msmsZ' - Your code *will* break as written on a different locale setting. this might sound picky but believe me: debugging those kind of problems can be a nightmare. better to stick to the ISO standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here but what you may want is

- IF parameter `@LetterCreated` is null then it should not be used as a filter at all
- IF the data in `RedFlagData.LETTERCREATETIME` is Null then it should be matched to a filter date of `'07/05/81'` FWR

Assuming that you have the 'allow nulls' check on the `RDL/RDLC` set for the `@LetterCreated` `parameter`, the `where` needs to be changed, the optional filter can be set like so:

```
ISNULL(@LetterCreated, LETTERCREATETIME) = ISNULL(LETTERCREATETIME, '07/05/81')
```

If you get rid of the magic date, then you can guarantee no date filter applied even if `LETTERCREATETIME` is null, by the filter:

```
ISNULL(@LetterCreated, LETTERCREATETIME) = ISNULL(LETTERCREATETIME) 
OR 
(@LetterCreated IS NULL AND LETTERCREATETIME IS NULL)
```

Thus:

```
ALTER PROC XYZ
(
  @LetterCreated DATETIME,
  @FirstName VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
  @LastName VARCHAR(20) = NULL
)
as
begin
    select  
        LETTERCREATETIME,
        Firstname,
        LastName,
    From 
        RedFlagAddress
    where 
    (
       ISNULL(@LetterCreated, LETTERCREATETIME) = LETTERCREATETIME
       OR
       (@LetterCreated IS NULL AND LETTERCREATETIME IS NULL)
    )
    AND LastName LIKE ISNULL(@LastName, '') + '%'
    AND FirstName LIKE ISNULL(@FirstName, '') + '%'
end
```

One caveat : The performance of this query will be terrible, given the amount of functional manipulation in the where clause, and the `LIKEs` and `ORs` - Hopefully `RedFlagAddress` is a relatively small table? If not, you may need to [rethink your approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160031/best-method-to-implement-a-filtered-search)

Comment: as you called out the performance will suffer as you are applying a function over the column ( no indexes for you! ). A better solution is presented here: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: This worked! I had to refresh my reports and everything. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `@lettercreated` date in the procedure. Variables defined within the procedure are not visible outside it.

You should declare the parameters as parameters, and set the default in the declaration

```
ALTER PROC yourproc
(
@LetterCreated DATETIME = '1950-1-1',
@FirstName VARCHAR(20) = '',
@LastName VARCHAR(20) = ''
)
as
begin
    select  
        LETTERCREATETIME,
        Firstname,
        LastName,
    From 
        RedFlagAddress
    where 
    (
         ISNULL(LETTERCREATETIME, '07/05/81') = @LetterCreated
         or
         @LetterCreated = '1950-1-1'
    )
    AND LastName LIKE @LASTNAME + '%' 
    AND FirstName LIKE @FirstNAME + '%'
end
```

Comment: I get an error that states that I cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

Comment: @user2084896 Are you sure? It sounds like you're running on SQL Server 2005 rather than 2008 stated in your question's tags. You'll have to declare the variables, then SET their values on a different line later on.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post that one. I didn't get an error message once I updated everything, but it still only see's the '1/1/1950' for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to podiluska's answer, you should set the parameters as part of the SP, as podiluska indicates, but then you should set the default values in SSRS, in the Parameters there.

This will let the users see the defaults and use those for subscriptions, or override them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter Proc Proc_Name
(
@LetterCreated DATETIME,
@FirstName VARCHAR(20) = null,
@LastName VARCHAR(20) = null
)
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

**This will pass null values as Default values to you Proc now you code should be able to handle null values if no values are provided for FirstName and LastName**